# no of ways of dividing 2n people into 2 groups

Tags: combinatorics

Find the ways to divide 2n people into two groups each of n people such that two people are always in different groups.

Comment: What have you attempted?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: i m confused do i have to take the factor 2nC2 for that 2 people??

Comment: i m confused do i have to take the factor 2nC2 for that 2 people??

Comment: Which two people are in different groups? Problem seems confusing, and a fuller explanation would be good, maybe one example of an OK and another of a not OK division of the people. [OR do you mean two specific people are in opposite groups?]

Comment: Let's name the people, say Anne and Barbara.  Place them in separate groups.  The problem reduces to selecting the people in Anne's group.  Once they have been selected, Barbara's group is completely determined.

Answer (score 2):

If two particular individuals $a,b$ have to be in different groups, then the number of ways to form the group containing $a$ is the number of ways to choose the remaining $n-1$ people from $2n-2$ people, which is ${2n-2 \choose n-1}$